# Induction proof - not sure how to proceed with next step

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Define two sequences $A_n, B_n$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
A_1 &= 1\\
A_2 &= 3\\
A_3 &= 2 \cdot 3+1=7 \\
A_4 &= 2 \cdot 7 + 3 = 17\\
A_5 &= 2 \cdot 17 + 7 = 41\\
A_n &= 2A_{n-1} + A_{n-2}\\
\\
B_1 &= 1\\
B_2 &= 2\\
B_3 &= 2 \cdot 2+1=5\\
B_4 &= 2 \cdot 5 + 2 = 12\\
B_5 &= 2 \cdot 12 + 5 = 29\\
B_n &= 2B_{n-1} + B_{n-2}
\end{align*}

Prove by induction that $A_n^2 - 2B_n^2 = (-1)^{n}$

For the base case with $n=1$ we have $A_n^2 - 2B_n^2 = 1-2 = -1 = (-1)^1$. Assume the assertion holds for $n=k$ and $n=k+1$. Then for the case $n = k+2$, 
$$
A_{k+2}^2 - 2 B_{k+2}^2 = (-1)^{k+2}
$$
Working on the left hand side,
\begin{align*}
\left( 2A_{k+1} + A_{k} \right)^2 - 2 \left( 2 B_{k+1}  + B_{k} \right)^2 &= 4A_{k+1}^2 + 4A_{k+1}A_{k} + A_{k}^2 -2 \left( 4B_{k+1}^2 + 4 B_{k+1}B_{k} + B_{k}^2 \right) \\
& = 4A_{k+1}^2 + 4A_{k+1}A_{k} + A_{k}^2 - 8B_{k+1}^2 - 8 B_{k+1}B_{k} - 2B_{k}^2 \\
& = 4A_{k+1}^2 - 8B_{k+1}^2 + A_{k}^2 - 2B_{k}^2  - 8 B_{k+1}B_{k} + 4A_{k+1}A_{k} \\
\end{align*}

I'm not sure how to deal with the last two terms: $- 8 B_{k+1}B_{k} + 4A_{k+1}A_{k}$

Comment: You need to show that:
$$2B_{k+1}B_k-A_{k+1}A_k=(-1)^{k+1} $$ so we can use induction to prove this ( induction inside induction) because I don't see why this can be done using only the assertion in $k$ and $k+1$ ( we may use the first values and the patterns between them)

Comment: I see how this works, thanks

Comment: $4(-1)^{k+1}+(-1)^k-4(-1)^{k+1}=(-1)^{k+2}$